# Plugins and html on page load - Split second where elements are all over the place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I have been making sites for years and still havent found a way on how to do this releiably. When using plugins like for instance fullpage.js for a split second when a user visits the site the content is all over the place until the css has loaded and the plugins then everything reorders as it should be. for example the site http://thisisdk.com uses fullpage and has a very heavy page with lots of videos yet from the start it loads seamlessly. I get that they have a loader but something tells me theres a lot of other very smart stuff going on aside from cdns etc.. Interested to hear other devs tricks and tips on how they overcome this without the use of preloaders

Comment: Looks like you're looking for some keywords to get started with your research. **Website/webpage optimization** is a broad topic. You're looking at optimizing HTML structure, optimizing code, then content minification and compression, optimizing external references (related to CDN usage), etc, etc. I hope this helps a little. Your question can hardly be answered better than "follow the fullpage.js guidelines to the letter", which @Alvaro, sort of, suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always recommend people to use load fullPage.js in the header contrary to the popular trend which adds JS files in the body.

**Why?**

Because I consider fullPage.js is essential for the correct visualization of your site. Without fullpage.js, your sections won't be of the correct size, they will be overlapping as you mention, slides content will be visible when it shouldn't...

Some of those things require of fullpage.js to run, detect dimensions of your content, set the slides to the right position etc.

You can check this in any of [the demo pages](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) provided by fullPage.js and you'll see there's no such blink.

**If you still don't want to go for this solution to speed up the loading of your site.**, what I would recommend is to use the critical CSS technique to set the size of your sections as fast as possible (even when fullpage.js is not initialized yet) and without any HTTP request (to speed it up even more)

Use the following inline styling in the header of your site:

```
<style>
    html,body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    .section,
    .slide,
    .fp-tableCell{
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
```

This will solve the problem with the blinking sections.

**Some of the possible problems**

- If you are using a conditional initialization of fullpage.js, this will still be applied even when you don't need it.
- If you destroy fullpage.js dynamically, this will still be applied when you don't need it.
- Sections with bigger content than the viewport won't have scroll bar until the plugin is loaded and initialized.
- Slides will be accessible for the user even when you don't want it by using `setAllowScrolling(false)` in some slides.

Comment: Cheers for that, great to have the down low from the creator of the plugin himself. Any idea when you will have a release that slows down the scroll speed of the overflow sections, that seems to be the only downfall of the plugin

Comment: Yeah, a plugin like fullpage.js should be loaded in the head. Anything else though can and should usually be loaded in the body.